# User management with Firebase yields a String UID how can I use the String value for UID with Agora.IO

Tags: swift, firebase, agora.io

I'm working on a project in iOS/Swift. I have implemented Firebase for user management and have deployed the Heroku server that Agora provides for token management.

I am able to send the UID of a user from firebase to the heroku server to generate a token using the url: `https://myserver.herokuapp.com/access_token?channel=\(channelName)&uid=\(uids[0])`.

The UID is a string and when I try to use this as a UID in the video controller to initiate a chat I get an error stating "Cannot assign value of type 'String' to type 'UInt'".

So is there a way to push a string to Agora or is there a popular solution for creating UInt version of the string based UID from Firebase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agora uses UInt ids, so the strings Firebase uses won't work. The simplest way to deal with this is to just let Agora handle channel IDs for you. You don't need to have a given user have the same UID every time they enter a channel, so you can just pass in 0 as the ID and then save what Agora passes back to you.

If you do really want each user to have a unique and constant ID with Agora, the best way would be to give each user a unique UInt id (either generating it yourself, or just letting Agora generate it for users who don't have one), and then save that to a Firebase database, or wherever you store user data already.

Comment: Thank you. That makes good sense. I am trying to follow along with this tutorial: https://medium.com/@unicornmobile/make-an-agora-ios-call-in-callkit-with-firebase-c1dabca135f3 so that i can integrate callKit. I used the example in here that creates a UInt value with this command "let localUID = UInt(UUID().hashValue)". I am still not clear how to push a video call in call kit to be received by another user. Is there a better or more thorough tutorial?

Comment: How would you correspond a user on Agora with a user in a database on Firebase? Random uInt doesn't tell anything about who it is.